# Problema con datos del arrayList en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

He descubierto un problema en la ejecución de mi código y no tengo ni idea de porque...
Resulta que tengo un for para meter datos de 2 alumnos, todo perfecto introduciendo los datos pero a la hora de visualizarlo con el método toString(), me visualiza todos los datos bien menos la fecha de nacimiento y las notas, los dos alumnos guardan ambos datos, del ultimo alumno introducido precisamente. Por ejemplo en los datos del alumno 1 le digo que ha nacido el 2/2/2000 con las notas: 2,2,2 y al alumno 2 le digo que ha nacido en el 3/3/2003 con las notas: 6,6,6. En la visualización de los datos ambos alumnos tienen la ultima fecha y notas introducidas. El nombre, dni etc aparece cada uno los suyos

Aquí el código:

```
public class Principal 
{

     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println("EJERCICIO ARRAYLIST EN JAVA\n");

         Scanner tecla = new Scanner (System.in);
         ArrayList <Alumnos> ArrayListAlumnos = new ArrayList();
         Alumnos objAlumnos = new Alumnos();
         Fecha objFecha = new Fecha();
         int notas[] = new int [3];
         int j;

         //Introducimos datos
         for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
         {
             objAlumnos = new Alumnos();

             System.out.print("\nNumero de expediente del "+(i+1)+" alumno: ");
             objAlumnos.setNumeroExpediente(tecla.nextInt());
             tecla.nextLine();//Limpiar buffer
             System.out.print("Dni: ");
             objAlumnos.setDni(tecla.nextLine());
             System.out.print("Nombre y apellidos: ");
             objAlumnos.setNombre(tecla.nextLine());
             System.out.println("Introduca fecha de nacimiento");
            do{             
                 System.out.print("Dia(1-31): ");
                 objFecha.setDia(tecla.nextInt());                              
                 System.out.print("Mes(1-12): ");
                 objFecha.setMes(tecla.nextInt());
                 System.out.print("Año(1980-2020): ");
                 objFecha.setAnio(tecla.nextInt());
                 if(objFecha.fechaCorrecta()==false)
                 {
                      System.out.println("\nFecha de nacimento incorrecta, introduzca de nuevo");
                 }
             }while(objFecha.fechaCorrecta()==false);           
             tecla.nextLine();//Limpiar buffer
             System.out.print("Curso: ");
             objAlumnos.setCurso(tecla.nextLine());
             System.out.println("\nIntroduzca notas correspondientes(1-10)");           
             for(j=0;j<3;j++)
             {              
                do{
                     System.out.print("Nota "+(j+1)+" : ");
                     notas[j]=tecla.nextInt();  
                     if(notas[j]<1 || notas[j]>10)
                     {
                         System.out.println("\nLa notas deben ir del 1 al 10, introduzca de nuevo");
                     }
                 }while(notas[j]<1 || notas[j]>10);
             }                      
             objAlumnos.setNotas(notas);        
             objAlumnos.setFecha_nacimiento(objFecha);//IMPORTANTE
             ArrayListAlumnos.add(objAlumnos);
         }

         //Visualizamos
         System.out.println("\n\nDATOS INTRODUCIDOS\n");
         for(int i=0;i<ArrayListAlumnos.size();i++)
         {
             objAlumnos = ArrayListAlumnos.get(i);
             System.out.println(objAlumnos.toString());
         }
     }  
 }
```

Mi clase fecha:

```
 public class Fecha
 {
     public int dia;
     public int mes;
     public int anio;

     public Fecha()
     {
        super();
        dia=1;
        mes=1;
        anio=2000;
     }

     public Fecha(int dia,int mes,int anio)
     {
         super();
         this.dia=dia;
         this.mes=mes;
         this.anio=anio;
     }

     public int getDia() {
         return dia;
     }

     public void setDia(int dia) {
         this.dia = dia;
     }

     public int getMes() {
         return mes;
     }

     public void setMes(int mes) {
         this.mes = mes;
     }

     public int getAnio() {
         return anio;
    }

    public void setAnio(int anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }

    public boolean fechaCorrecta()
    {
        boolean diaCorrecto,mesCorrecto,anioCorrecto;

        anioCorrecto = anio >= 1980 && anio <=2020;
        mesCorrecto = mes >=1 && mes <=12;

        switch(mes)
        {
            case 2:
                if(anioBisiesto())
                {
                    diaCorrecto = dia >= 1 && dia <=29;
                }
                else
                {
                diaCorrecto = dia >= 1 && dia <=28;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
                diaCorrecto = dia >=1 && dia <=30;
                break;
             default:
                diaCorrecto = dia >=1 && dia <=31;
        }
        return diaCorrecto && mesCorrecto && anioCorrecto;
    }

    private boolean anioBisiesto() {

        return (anio % 4 == 0 && anio % 100 !=0 || anio % 400 == 0);
    }       
}
```

Mi clase alumno:

```
public class Alumnos extends Datos_Personales
{
    private int numeroExpediente;
    private String curso;
    private int notas[];

    public Alumnos()
    {
        super();
        numeroExpediente=0;
        curso = new String();
        int notas[] = new int [3];
    }

    public Alumnos(String dni,String nombre,Fecha fecha_nacimiento,int numeroExp,String curso,int notas[])
    {
        super(dni,nombre,fecha_nacimiento);
        this.numeroExpediente=numeroExp;
        this.curso=curso;
        this.notas[3]=notas[3];
    }

    public int getNumeroExpediente() {
        return numeroExpediente;
    }

    public void setNumeroExpediente(int numeroExpediente) {
        this.numeroExpediente = numeroExpediente;
    }

    public String getCurso() {
        return curso;
    }

     public void setCurso(String curso) {
         this.curso = curso;
    }

    public int[] getNotas() {
        return notas;
    }

    public void setNotas(int[] notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
   }

    public String toString()
    {
         return "\nNumero de expediente = " + numeroExpediente + "\nDni = " + dni + "\nNombre = " + nombre + "\nFecha de nacimiento = "+
            fecha_nacimiento.dia+"/"+fecha_nacimiento.mes+"/"+fecha_nacimiento.anio + 
            "\nCurso = " + curso + "\n1 Nota = "+ notas[0] + "\n2 Nota = " + notas[1] + "\n3 Nota = " + notas[2];
    }   
 }
```

Comment: Recomiendo que agregues los codigos de las clase Alumnos y Fecha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas haciendo referencia a la misma referencia de fecha,
Cree el objeto `Fecha` dentro del `for`

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    objAlumnos = new Alumnos();
    Fecha fechaNacimiento = new Fecha();
```

int notas[] = new int[3];

Posterior a esto le da los valores

```
do{             
    System.out.print("Dia(1-31): ");
    fechaNacimiento.setDia(tecla.nextInt());                              
    System.out.print("Mes(1-12): ");
    fechaNacimiento.setMes(tecla.nextInt());
    System.out.print("Año(1980-2020): ");
    fechaNacimiento.setAnio(tecla.nextInt());
    if(fechaNacimiento.fechaCorrecta()==false)
    {
       System.out.println("\nFecha de nacimento incorrecta, introduzca de nuevo");
    }
}while(fechaNacimiento.fechaCorrecta()==false);
```

y Por ultimo lo guarda en el Alummo

```
objAlumnos.setFecha_nacimiento(fechaNacimiento);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciona perfecto, pero las notas siguen saliendo mal

Comment: Haga lo mismo, cree el arreglo de notas dentro del `for`

Comment: Lo tengo hecho no? Mi array de notas esta dentro del for

Comment: No, la instancia del arreglo de notas esta por fuera del `for`  `Alumnos objAlumnos = new Alumnos();
         Fecha objFecha = new Fecha();
         int notas[] = new int [3];`  coloque  `int notas[] = new int [3];` dentro del for

Comment: Vale, es verdad todo perfecto ahora, gracias!!